# How can I use ClojureScript's Hiccups library in nbb

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, babashka

I am using the example from the nbb docs on [calling nbb from node](https://github.com/babashka/nbb#calling-nbb-from-javascript), which works as expected, generally, using the following (slightly modified) snippets:

```
;; example.cljs
(ns example)

(defn greet [name] (println "Hello," name)

;; this JS object is the return value of loadFile:
#js {:greet greet}
```

```
// index.js
import { loadFile } from 'nbb'

// destructure JS object returned from .cljs file:
const { greet } = await loadFile('example.cljs')

// execute the foo function
greet("World");
```

```
$ node index.js
Hello, World
```

I would like to use ClojureScript's [hiccups](https://github.com/teropa/hiccups) library, but I just can't quite seem to work out how to get it wired up.

### What I tried

I tried adding the hiccups library to an nbb.edn file (as suggested elsewhere in the nbb docs), like this:

```
{:deps
 {hiccups/hiccups {:mvn/version "0.3.0"}}}
```

then requiring it in the example.cljs file like this (adapted from the hiccups docs)

```
(ns example
  (:require [hiccups :as hiccups]))

;; ... etc.
```

I also tried other things that were more or less stabs in the dark that didn't do anything useful.

### Errors

But I just get errors that get a bit too cryptic for me to figure out yet:

```
$ node index.js 
Downloading dependencies...
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.main
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/sirrobert/.clojure/.cpcache/A4CEF68F951217FE6FE54759160B5276.cp (No such file or directory)
... 100 more lines ...
```

Clearly it is attempting to download the deps when nbb starts to interpret the script, but theres some babashka failure...

### Request

Can someone provide an example script that shows how to wire this up?  Preferrably with comments. Just a simple `(println (html [:span "Hello, World!"]))` sort of script would be enough to get me started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't fix the root cause of your issue but:

nbb comes with reagent built in which you can also use to render hiccup.

```
$ npm install nbb react-dom
$ npx nbb
user=> (require '[reagent.dom.server :refer [render-to-string]])
nil
user=> (render-to-string [:div [:p "Hello"]])
"<div><p>Hello</p></div>"
```

To debug your deps issue, you could try the following:

```
bb --config nbb.edn -e nil
```

and see what it prints.

Feel free to follow up in the Clojurians Slack nbb / babashka channels.